# website entity framework migration ArgumentException

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, database-migration

I am learning how to use entity framework

After setting up a database model, I can easily perform migrations in web applications and console projects.

But when I create a database model in a website project and perform migrations, the console prompt me

```
System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Server stack trace: 
   at EnvDTE.Properties.Item(Object index)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at EnvDTE.Properties.Item(Object index)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project, String propertyName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

what can i do about it?
Q2. If I create a web application project, how can I deploy it? Other than FTP, I don't know any other means to deploy a web site.

Comment: Q1. How are you running your migrations?  Q2. Look at web deploy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx

Comment: i just typed enable-migrations. that's all.
i don't know what i should put for the other parameters

Comment: I have this exact problem.  Entity Framework works fine using the 'Enable-Migrations' in web applications and console applications.  However when trying to use it within a website project, I get error messages and nothing that I've found helps (mainly people saying to pass in project name into command but that doesn't work either)

Comment: Oh yes. Migration only works for web applications. It doesn't work for website projects.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is causing the issue, but you might be able to get around it by creating a separate assembly in which your model and context are contained, then enabling migrations on that project. Reference that project from your website project.